# How to add an array of hash tables to an array powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

I'm trying to add an array of hashtables to an existing array of hastables in Powershell, adding a single item works fine but I can't seem to find out how to add multiple hashtables to an existing array.

For example I have the below;

```
$ToAdd = @()
$ToAdd += (@{ 
        id   = "1234";
        type = "Scope";
    })
```

I then want to be able to add the $ToAdd array of hashtables to the object below ($helloBody.helloAccess.AccessRequired)

```
  $HelloBody = [ordered] @{
    "helloAccess" = @(
        @{
            hello = "hello"
            accessRequired = @(
                @{
                    id   = "random guid" 
                    type = "item 123"   
                }
                
                
            )
                              
        }
    )
    
}
```

How is it possible to add an array of hashtables into another array?

When I try `$helloBody.helloAccess.AccessRequired += $ToAdd`, I get the following error:

```
A hash table can only be added to another hash table.
```

Comment: What is your question? Is `$helloBody.helloAccess.AccessRequired = $ToAdd` (or `$helloBody.helloAccess.AccessRequired += $ToAdd`) not working?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes that's correct, I would like to know how to add my array of hashtables into an existing array, and yes += does not work

Comment: What happens instead? :) Please be mindful that we cannot see your screen, you're gonna  have to describe the situation in detail if you want help

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen sure, Okay so what happens if I do a += $ToAdd, I get an error returned saying "A hash table can only be added to another hash table" The full error is below; A hash table can only be added to another hash table.
`At line:1 char:1
+ $UpdateAppBody.requiredResourceAccess.resourceAccess += $test
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddHashTableToNonHashTable`

Comment: If I manually add in the `$ToAdd` into the $helloBody.helloAccess.AccessRequired object that gives me the desired output however I need to be able to achieve this programmatically. The `$ToAdd` array of hashtables will be created fro objects from a `ForEach-Object` and then added into the main body which will later be POST via HTTP rest method

Answer (score 3):

**In order to update the `.accessRequired` entry of your nested hashtable, you must avoid [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration)**:

In your case, this means that you must access the first element of the *array* stored in `.helloAccess` *explicitly*:

```
$helloBody.helloAccess[0].AccessRequired += $ToAdd
```

Omitting `[0]` doesn't work, because member-access enumeration (regrettably) *unwraps* a *single-element* array instead of reporting it as such.

In concrete terms:

- `$helloBody.helloAccess` performs member-access enumeration on the single-element array stored in that property, and returns the `AccessRequired` entry *from each element*.
- The one and only `.AccessRequired` entry is itself a single-element array, and member-access enumeration *unwraps* that single-element array, yielding its only element *directly*, which is a hashtable.
- `+=` / `+`  on a hashtable only works if the operand is *also* a hashtable, in which case the entries are *merged*; using any other type as the operand causes the error you saw (the error message is a bit confusing, but that is what it is trying to tell you).

Note:

- **Member-access enumeration** unwraps single-element arrays, because it **emulates the behavior of the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet in the *pipeline***, which, as cmdlets generally do, emits objects to the pipeline *one by one* by *enumerating* them, so that `Write-Output -NoEnumerate @('foo') | ForEach-Object { $_ }` yields the same as `'foo' | ForEach-Object { $_ }`: A single-element array is treated the same as its one and only element, and the array wrapper is lost.

  - For reasons of backward compatibility this behavior is unlikely to change; see [GitHub issue #6802](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6802) for a discussion.
- More generally, note that **you can only use member-access enumeration for *getting* property values, not for *setting* them**:

  - For instance, the following fails:

    ```
    # ERROR: "The property 'foo' cannot be found on this object..."
    @(@{ foo = 1 }, @{ foo = 2 }).foo = 42
    ```

    - However, due to the unwrapping behavior, if the result happens to be only a *single* object, updating a *property of* that single object happens to work (which is why your assignment worked *in principle*, but failed due to an incompatible operand):

      ```
      # OK, but only because the single-element array wrapper
      # is effectively ignored.
      @(@{ foo = @{ bar = 1 } }).foo.bar = 42
      ```
  - Preventing setting is deemed by-design, to prevent inadvertent changes; either way, the error message is confusing - see [GitHub issue #5271](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5271) for a discussion and a workaround.

Comment: You're a legend, I must admit I do feel a little embarrassed now as i've been doing a lot of searching around for this and none have worked as of yet. Very good to know that's now working perfectly and great to know for the future!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Russeller, glad to hear it helped - please see my update, which explains the behavior in more detail and provides background information. No need to feel embarrassed at all - this is tricky stuff, both for newcomers and experienced users (even though I'm familiar with the underlying problem, it took me a while to spot it in your code).